# Get Exclusive Count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm trying to get the count of PlanIds that are exclusive records for a certain location in an m-n table.

Imagine that I have the following table:

```
Id
PlanId
LocationId
```

I want to retrieve the count of `PlanId`s  that only have one `LocationId` associated with it

What I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(PlanId)
FROM PLANLOCATION
WHERE PLANLOCATION = LocationId
```

Can you guys, help me, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method, that uses two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT PlanId
      FROM PLANLOCATION 
      GROUP BY PlanId
      HAVING MIN(LocationId) = MAX(LocationId)
     ) p;
```

Another method uses `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select count(distinct pl.planid)
from planlocation pl
where not exists (select 1
                  from planlocation pl2
                  where pl2.planid = pl.planid and
                        pl2.locationid <> pl.locationid
                 );
```

Note that `count(distinct)` can be just `count(*)` if `planlocation` has no duplicates.